# Одновременная работа с БД нескольких запросов

Tags: php, mysql

При работе с базой данных  появляется проблема.

При отправке запроса (ajax или синхронного, не важно), который может выполняться длительное время, секунд 10-40, база данных как бы "зависает", т.е. никакие другие запросы связанные с БД в течении этого времени не работают. Подскажите, как одновременно работать с БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя локается файл сессии. После того, как забрал на сервере данные из сессии, добавь функцию `<?php session_write_close() ?>` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-write-close.php
Эта функция решит проблему. 
Сама база данных не зависает. Она рассчитана на множество одновременных запросов.

Answer (score 1):

В целом, решение очевидное - **фронтенд в принципе некогда не должен выполнять запросов, время исполнения которых превышает 0,1 сек.**
Плюс, ни один скрипт в системе не должен исполнять запросы, блокирующие БД, время исполнения которых превышает 0,1 сек.

Ну а проблема автора вопроса, скорее всего, вызвана не БД, а механизмом сессий.

Если просуммировать все вышесказанное, то никакие фронтенд скрипты не должны работать дольше 0,1 - максимум - 0,5 секунды. Все же длительные операции, такие как построение отчетов, обработка изображений и видео, и все такое прочее - должны производиться **в фоновом режиме.** Начинающим пользователям РНР очень рекомендуется изучать современные веб-технологии, регистрируясь на популярных сайтах, таких как Вконтакте, Фейсбук, Ютьюб и прочих, и интересоваться тем, как на этих сайтах решаются стоящие перед ними вопросы.

За скрипт, который через полчаса должен будет отдать результат своей работы клиенту, и **все это время держит соединение с браузером**, начинающего пользователя РНР будут бить по рукам, очень больно. А потом отберут печеньки и разжалуют в курьеры. Потому что ему все равно никогда не стать продолжающим пользователем пхп.

Потому что продолжающие уже начинают потихоньку думать не только как решить прямо сейчас стоящую перед ними проблему, но и как н**е поломать при этом всё остальное.** А вот с этим-то как раз у любителей поотвечать на вопросы на Stack Overflow очень большая проблема.

Comment: а если большой репорт?

Comment: Можно запросто держать соединение около 25 сек. К примеру, если реализуется лонг поллинг. Как раз в таких ситуациях и возникает проблема с локом файла сессии. Только на сервере нужно реализовать механизм таймаута с таким же интервалом - максимум 25 сек.

Comment: @Shorty, прекращайте д'Артаньянить и поливать других участников сообщества. Одинаково хороши ответы в духе quick-and-dirty и решения, рассчитанные на серьезный production. Автор вопроса сам поймет, что ему актуальнее.

Comment: @Nofate в условиях недостатка нормальной информации в рунете и полностью заваленного php-mysql-кодом десятилетней давности гугла данное д'Артаньянство лишним не будет.

Comment: @andreymal, но не в каждом же втором ответе.